# How to increase the size of JScrollPane pane?

Tags: java, jscrollpane

> ```
>   scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
>   panel1.add( scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER );
> ```

Is there a way I can make the scrollPane bigger (wider) ?

Comment: I don't understand the question.. Resize it's parent element..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table, 
                                        JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                                        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
JScrollBar bar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
bar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 0));
```

This works. I figured it out.

Comment: [Don't set the preferred size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi). Override `getPreferredSize` instead.

Answer (score 2):

When using Border Layout you don't control the size of the somponents in it Consider using [GridBag Layout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

Answer (score 2):

The `JScrollPane` is as big as the element it holds. You should make those element(s) wider.

Also, there is the `setSize()`-method. But you'll most likely want to use the `setPreferredSize()`-method as mentioned by mre.

Comment: `setPreferredSize()` is probably more preferable.